# Webserver is loading css files, but the styles are not getting displayed

Tags: css, ruby, web, webserver

**Edit**: Found something interesting. The CSS works on IE8, but not on Firefox. I'm guessing this is a character encoding issue?

I'm trying to learn how to write my own web server, and I managed to get the server up and running, but for some reason it won't display css. Javascript however, works just fine. The css file gets loaded, but the styles don't show up in Firebug. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Code for the server is shown below. To run the server you just call "start" an empty list. Alternatively, you can pull the whole codebase here if you want: https://github.com/dm9600/webserver

```
require 'socket'

def start(args)
   webserver = create_server args
   basepath = './app/'

   while (session = webserver.accept)
      puts "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\nContent-type:text/html\n\n"
      session.print "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\nContent-type:text/html\n\n"
      request = session.gets
      puts "request" + request
      trimmedrequest = trim_request(request)
      filename = trimmedrequest.chomp
      begin
         displayfile = find_file(filename)
         content = displayfile.read()
         session.print content
      rescue Errno::ENOENT
         session.print "File not found"
      end
      session.close
   end
end 

def create_server(args)
   command = args[0]
   #default port is going to be 3333
   port = 3333
   #default address will be localhost
   address = "localhost"
   port = args[1] if args[0].instance_of? String and args[0].eql? "p"
   puts "Server created at #{address} and port #{port}"
   TCPServer.new address, port
end 

def trim_request(request)
   request.gsub(/GET\ \//, '').gsub(/\ HTTP.*/, '')
end 

def find_file(path)
   basepath = "./app/"
   if path.empty?
      full_path = basepath + 'index.html'
   else
      full_path = basepath + path
   end 
   File.open full_path, 'r'
end
```

The html I'm running. This is located in /app/index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <script src="js/application.js"></script>
      <title>CSS-Test</title>

      <link type="text/css" href="css/application.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
   </head>
   <body>

      <h1>CSS-Test</h1>

      <div id="box-one">
         <p>This is box one.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="box-two">
         <p>This is box two.</p>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

The css I'm trying to run. It's located in /app/css/application.css

```
.someclass {
   background: blue;
}

* {
   background: black;
}
```

**Edit:** Had the wrong css file location here.

Comment: Make sure the css link in your html is correct, right now it says "css/aplication.css" but you say the file is in app/application.css

Comment: Oops, nice catch. I put the wrong location here. It's now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As "mu is too short" points out in the comments, I made a huge newbie mistake sending everything back with `Content-type: text/html`, which is obviously a big problem! All I had to do is associate the right files with the right content types, and everything works. Here's the fixed `server.rb` file:

```
require 'socket'

def start(args)
   webserver = create_server args
   basepath = './app/'

   while (session = webserver.accept)
      request = session.gets
      trimmedrequest = trim_request(request)
      ct = get_content_type trimmedrequest
      session.print "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\nContent-type:#{ct}\n\n"
      puts"HTTP/1.1 200/OK\nContent-type:#{ct}\n\n" 
      filename = trimmedrequest.chomp
      begin
         displayfile = find_file(filename)
         content = displayfile.read()
         session.print content
      rescue Errno::ENOENT
         session.print "File not found"
      end
      session.close
   end
end 

def create_server(args)
   command = args[0]
   #default port is going to be 3333
   port = 3333
   #default address will be localhost
   address = "localhost"
   port = args[1] if args[0].instance_of? String and args[0].eql? "p"
   puts "Server created at #{address} and port #{port}"
   TCPServer.new address, port
end 

def trim_request(request)
   request.gsub(/GET\ \//, '').gsub(/\ HTTP.*/, '')
end 

def find_file(path)
   basepath = "./app/"
   if path.empty?
      full_path = basepath + 'index.html'
   else
      full_path = basepath + path
   end 
   File.open full_path, 'r'
end 

def get_content_type(path)
    ext = File.extname(path)
    return "text/html"  if ext.include? ".html" or ext.include? ".htm"
    return "text/plain" if ext.include? ".txt"
    return "text/css"   if ext.include? ".css"
    return "image/jpeg" if ext.include? ".jpeg" or ext.include? ".jpg"
    return "image/gif"  if ext.include? ".gif"
    return "image/bmp"  if ext.include? ".bmp"
    return "text/plain" if ext.include? ".rb"
    return "text/xml"   if ext.include? ".xml"
    return "text/xml"   if ext.include? ".xsl"
    return "text/html"
end
```